# How can in add an interactive python project in a React portfolio

Tags: python, reactjs, google-earth-engine

I am a beginner to the coding world. But i would like to know how I can effectively integrate interactive visualizations created in Python and Google Earth Engine into my React portfolio while preserving interactivity without resorting to video or GIF formats?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.